# How to split large .a static library?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, static-libraries, unix-ar

Is there a possibility to split large `.a` files into multiple smaller ones?

I'm currently having an issue with a `.a` file being multiple GiB large and GCC raises an error even with the flag `-mcmodel=medium`.

Comment: Do you have the sources?

Comment: Yes I do have the sources.

Comment: Then compile them into multiple static libraries instead of one giant one.  It's a much easier problem than trying to split up large compiled library.

Comment: It is easy to subdivide a static library into smaller ones without recompiling
any code, but this will not solve your `mcmodel` error. Edit your post to show
us the exact commandline and resulting error(s), and it might be possible to help.

Comment: You can extract all the object files from a large static library, and then package subsets of the functions into smaller libraries.   However, you'd probably have a hard time working out which subsets make sense in the smaller libraries to avoid recursive dependencies between the smaller libraries.  I'm not sure this would  evade your problems with the library size overall (but I don't know that it won't help either).

Comment: Once upon a very long time ago, there was a pair of programs, `lorder` and `tsort`. You used `lorder` to find which object files depended on which others, and used `tsort` to do a topological sort on the dependencies generated by `lorder` to give an order in which to place the object files into a library. This was necessary in the days before `ranlib`, and later the `ar` program being able to generate the lookup information without an explicit invocation of `ranlib`. This was late 70s through late 80s, or thereabouts. You can still find `tsort`; you may be out of luck with `lorder`.

Comment: I found [`lorder`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/lorder/) documented.  That means the source is out there too.  One place where you can find `lorder` and `tsort` is in the [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/) source code at GitHub under ([freebsd](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/tree/master/usr.bin))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use binutils tool "ar":

```
ar -x libbig.a
```

for extracting the objects from the archive and

```
ar -r libsmall.a obj1.o obj2.o obj3.o
```

for creating a new archive.